# Is it safe to point to an array access from a pointer that goes beyond the array?

Tags: c

Apologies for the loopy question wording, but it boils down to this. I'm maintaining C code that does something like this:

```
char *foo = "hello"
int i;
char *bar;

i = strlen(foo);
bar = &foo[i];
```

Is this safe? Could there be a case where the `foo[i]` leads to a segmentation fault, before it gets a pointer, and isn't covered by the compiler?

Comment: Either way, `foo[i]` is the null terminator of that string, which exists.

Comment: You can legitimately create the address `bar = &foo[i+1];` but you cannot legitimately dereference that pointer.  But the basic `bar = &foo[i];` is completely kosher and won't cause trouble as it points to the null byte at the end of the string.

Comment: Ahh good point sorry! I completely forgot about the null terminator...

Comment: @Dunedubby: Note that `strlen` is contingent on the *first* NUL terminator reached too.

Comment: why not `bar = foo + i`

Comment: @bobra Yes that is what I was thinking too

Comment: @bobra: You could write `i[foo]` if you wanted. Horses for courses.

Comment: Also note that `char * foo = "hello";` is short for `const char * foo = "hello"`, a pointer to anywhere in that string constant cannot change the value

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No. No. No. In C it's a char* type, in C++ it's a const char* type. In either language the pointed-to string is read only, i.e. you're correct in that it behaves like a const char* type. `const` was introduced late into C.

Comment: @Bathsheba fair enough, it's just that I'm not sure what would be more correct. It's kind of like the `static` storage class is used, but I can't remember if the string stays in memory until return of `main`

Comment: OT:  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, NOT a `int`  Your compiler should have told you about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to set a pointer one beyond the end of an array (although you are not actually doing that in your code - you are pointing to the NUL terminator).

Note though that the behaviour on *dereferencing* a pointer set to one past the end of an array would be undefined.

(Note that `&foo[i]` is required by the C standard to be evaluated without dereferencing the pointer: i.e. `&foo[i + 1]` is valid, but `foo[i + 1]` on its own isn't.)

Comment: `&foo[i + 1]` *may* be valid but it crashes with MSVC in debug mode, or at least used to, in some versions (then again MSVC doesn’t really implement C). Either way I don’t recommend writing such code, `foo + i + 1` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm maintaining C code that does something like this:
>
> ```
> char *foo = "hello"
> int i;
> char *bar;
>
> i = strlen(foo);
> bar = &foo[i];
> ```
>
> Is this safe?

The code presented conforms with the current and all past C language standards, and has the same well-defined behavior according to each.  In particular, be aware that C string literals represent *null-terminated* character arrays, just like all other C strings, so in the example code. `foo[i]` refers to the terminator, and `&foo[i]` points *into* the array (to its last element), not outside it.

Moreover, C also allows obtaining a pointer to just past the end of an array, so even `1 + &foo[i]` is valid and conforming. It is not permitted to dereference such a pointer, but you can perform pointer arithmetic and comparisons with it (subject to the normal constraints).

> Could there be a case where the foo[i] leads to a
>   segmentation fault, before it gets a pointer, and isn't covered by the
>   compiler?

C does not have anything whatever to say about segmentation faults.  Whenever you receive one, either your implementation has exhibited non-conformance, or (almost always) your program is exercising undefined behavior.  The code presented conforms, subject to a correct declaration of `strlen()` being in scope, and if it appears as part of a complete program that conforms and does not otherwise exercise UB then there is no reason short of general skepticism to fear a segfault.